# RestClient ExecuteAsync method deprecated

Tags: c#, restsharp

Since I have upgraded my RestSharp package, it seems that this piece of code is now deprecated:

```
var taskCS = new TaskCompletionSource<IRestResponse>();
var client = new RestClient(url + endPoint);
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);

client.ExecuteAsync(request, response =>
{
    taskCS.SetResult(response);
});

...

return await taskCS.Task;
```

Here's the warning I get:

> RestClientExtensions.ExecuteAsync(IRestClient, IRestRequest,
>   Action)' is obsolete: 'Use ExecuteAsync that returns
>   Task'

Do you have examples that use ExecuteAsync method that returns Task?

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 5):

Just await the task returned from ExecuteAsync, and you've got your response object:

```
var response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);
```